# Is there a way to get this "send to printer" Java method to work?

Tags: java, pdf, printing

```
public static void sendPdfToPrinter(String epsilon)
{
    FileInputStream psStream = null;
    try {
        psStream = new FileInputStream(epsilon);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
          ffne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (psStream == null) {
            return;
        }
    DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);  
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset);

    // this step is necessary because I have several printers configured
    PrintService myPrinter = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++)
    {
        String svcName = services[i].toString();          
        System.out.println("service found: "+ svcName); 
        if (svcName.contains("series"))
        {
            myPrinter = services[i];
            System.out.println("my printer found: "+svcName);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (myPrinter != null) {            
        DocPrintJob job = myPrinter.createPrintJob();
        try {
        job.print(myDoc, aset);

        } catch (Exception pe) {pe.printStackTrace();}
    } else {
        System.out.println("no printer services found");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    //Testing t = new Testing();
    String DEST = ("C:/Users/Brian/Desktop/SO046201R-17/TestingAlpha/6FS-2m.pdf");
    sendPdfToPrinter(DEST);
}
```

I'm currently writing a program that'll write text to a series of PDF files and then send them to a printer. I've got the writing to the PDF part done, but whenever I try passing the file to the "sendPdfToPrinter" method I encounter problems. So far I've tested a HP Deskjet printer and a Canon Inkjet printer with no success (former gave a "Java Document error" message and latter wouldn't add file to the queue). I suppose my question boils down to this:

Is the problem with the code or with the printers I'm using? Is there a workaround?

Using Mark's edit:

```
public static void sendPdfToPrinter(String epsilon) throws 
InvalidPasswordException, IOException
{
    FileInputStream psStream = null;
    try {
        psStream = new FileInputStream(epsilon);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
          ffne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (psStream == null) {
            return;
        }
    DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PDDocument myDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(epsilon));  
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService[] services = 
    PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset);

    // this step is necessary because I have several printers configured
    PrintService myPrinter = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++)
    {
        String svcName = services[i].toString();          
        System.out.println("service found: "+ svcName); 
        if (svcName.contains("series"))
        {
            myPrinter = services[i];
            System.out.println("my printer found: "+svcName);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (myPrinter != null) {            
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        try {
            job.setPrintService(myPrinter);
            job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(myDoc));
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            // Handle the exception.
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("no printer services found");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because your printers don't natively support PDFs. I actually managed to print a PDF with your code, but it printed it as it would look if a PDF file was opened as a text file.

One solution is to use Apache's PDF library for Java: [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). The file can be loaded like so:

```
PDDocument myDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(epsilon));
```

To print the file, use `PrinterJob` instead of `DocPrintJob`:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

try {
    job.setPrintService(myPrinter);
    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(myDoc));
    job.print();
} catch (PrinterException e) {
    // Handle the exception.
}
```

Comment: Is there an instructional video on how to install this Apache PDF library? I needed a visual when I was installing the library for iTextPDF.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, you need to add the jar file for the library to your project's libraries. Refer to your IDE's documentation for how to do that. If you are compiling from command line, add the path to the jar with the `-cp` switch: `javac -cp ".;/path/to/library.jar;" MyClass.java`

Comment: Is this for Linux? Cause I'm using Windows.

Comment: No, you can compile .java files from a terminal (e.g. cmd.exe in Windows) using the `javac` command.

Comment: I implemented your edit in the question. Did I write this correctly?

Comment: Looks good. You can remove the file stream code at the top since it is no longer needed to load the file.

Comment: I've tested out your code and it works. A million thanks to you! If I may ask one more question: is there a way to send the file to a printer marked as my PC's default printer?

Comment: `PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService()`